# Problems converting from shape to topojson

Tags: d3.js, geojson, shapefile, gdal, topojson

I'm trying to convert a shapefile of mexican municipalities into a topojson and displaying it using d3.js using this tutorial http://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/#converting-data. I've managed to convert it but I can't manage to display it. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

This is my workflow so far:

1) Download and unzip the shapefile

```
wget http://mapserver.inegi.org.mx/MGN/mgm2010v5_0a.zip 
unzip mgm2010v5_0a.zip
```

2) Converting to JSON, reprojecting to lat-long and subsetting the shapefile

```
ogr2ogr  -f GeoJSON -t_srs EPSG:4326 -where "CVE_ENT IN ('09')" df.json Municipios_2010_5A.shp
```

3) Converting to topojson

```
topojson --id-property OID -p name=OID -p name -o df2.json df.json
```

4) And creating the html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

/* CSS goes here. */

</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
<script>

var width = 960,
height = 1160;

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("width", width)
.attr("height", height);

 d3.json("df2.json", function(error, df2) {
 svg.append("path")
  .datum(topojson.feature(df2, df2.objects.df))
  .attr("d", d3.geo.path().projection(d3.geo.mercator()));
 });

 </script>
```

If I run the html I just get a blank page. Any ideas about what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Is that your whole html file, or just a snippet? If that's the whole thing, you need to add a `</body>` end tag at the end.

Comment: A useful diagnositic tool available in most browsers is to hit `F12` to pull up the console and see what's actually in the document. Alternately, you could use View Source, though I'm unsure if that will capture post-load additions to the page made by javascript.

Comment: Yeah sorry about that. But even if I add the body end tag I still get no output. This is what I get from the console. Seems like it isn't drawing anything.




    <html>

    <head></head>
    <body>
        <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
        <script></script>
        <svg width="960" height="1160">
            <path></path>
        </svg>
    </body>

    </html>

Comment: To be clear, your topojson output isn't empty, right? It's generating the data correctly and just not displaying it? Or is it not generating any data, and then displaying the lack of data correctly?

Comment: It's definitely not empty and looks like topojson.  Here's a link to it if you are willing to take a look! https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/2ik1mi3724v16bu/DF2.json

Comment: Looking at the output html in jfiddle, it looks like the path is empty. Do you have a tutorial or reference page you're following, preferably with a working example? I'm thinking maybe the path isn't getting generated correctly, and thus your svg would be empty.

Comment: Yep. I'm using this  http://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/#converting-data

Comment: have you tried just `d3.json("df2.json", function(error, df2) { console.log(df2); });` to see if it's getting the json file at all?

Comment: Yeah, it's getting to it.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm lost on this one. I'd recommend trying to split out all the details like in the tutorial after the tiny version of the map, and seeing if they all hold the values they're supposed to.

Comment: Thanks for the help anyway! I'll keep trying

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The simplest option, if you aren’t particular about the projection, is to just use the projection provided by the shapefile (Lambert Conformal Conic). Use [topojson](https://github.com/mbostock/topojson/wiki/Command-Line-Reference)’s --width and --height command-line flags to rescale the projected shapefile to a reasonable size. For example, if you want something 960px wide, you could say:

```
topojson --width=960 --margin 20 --simplify=.1 -o mx.json -- municipalities.shp
```

(This also simplifies in screen coordinates, conveniently.)

A full example with a Makefile is at [bl.ocks.org/9265467](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/9265467):

[image: mexico]

If, on the other hand, you want to specify your own projection, then it’s reasonable to use ogr2ogr to undo the projection, and then define a projection in the browser. But in that case, you’ll want to specify the projection parameters appropriately. For example, to recreate the same projection in the browser, you can say:

```
var projection = d3.geo.conicConformal()
    .rotate([102, 0])
    .center([0, 24])
    .parallels([17.5, 29.5])
    .scale(1850)
    .translate([width / 2, height / 2]);
```

(Fiddle with the center and scale as you like to fit your desired viewport.) This alternative approach is demonstrated at [bl.ocks.org/9265674](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/9265674):

[image: mexico 2]

I generally prefer using projected coordinates (the first approach, above), as they are faster to render and simplification is more efficient. On the other hand, if you want to change the projection dynamically — admittedly unlikely with such a complex shapefile — then projecting in the browser is the way to go. And projecting in the browser is nice during development because it’s easier to change the parameters and reload.