# Topojson equivalent to ogr2ogr -clipdst?

Tags: topojson

I'am digging in for [reprojection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23086493/), which is often followed by cliping to work on "just the needed data". I noticed that both ogr2ogr could be used for reprojection :

```
#using ogr2ogr, then crop via ogr2ogr -clipsrc 
ogr2ogr -f 'ESRI Shapefile' -t_srs 'EPSG:...' output.shp input.shp
# or using topojson:
topojson --projection 'd3.geo.albers()' -q 1e5 --id-property=name -- input.shp -o output.json
```

Ogr2ogr privide cliping capabilities on shapefiles :

```
ogr2ogr -clipsrc $(WEST) $(NORTH) $(EAST) $(SOUTH) output.shp input.shp
```

**But is there a clip function via topojson ?** that i'am not aware of. **And if not, how could I crop my topojson data** let's say in the bounding box W:0, N:55, E:15, S: 40 (Europe), so I don't have to load json for the whole earth.

[Topojson API of Reference](https://github.com/mbostock/topojson/wiki/API-Reference).

Comment: "You can clip in conjunction with --projection by specifying a clipped projection (e.g., clipAngle, clipExtent)." ([RETWEET of @mbostoc](https://twitter.com/mbostock/status/534830742682230784))

Comment: Seems [there are](http://bl.ocksplorer.org/#/search/d3.geo.clipExtent) some interesting case-studies.